# Puppeteer navigate through pages and evaluate each one

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm building a little application for development purposes that goes to the TripAdvisor website, loads up a page, and grabs the results of that page and logs it to the console. I'm having some troubles trying to find out how to click through to the "next" page, and then re-evaluate the contents and get all of the information from the second page to add to some array, my code currently is:

```js
// require Puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// launch Puppeteer with options, wait for it to launch
puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false
}).then(async browser => {

  // go to our page of choice, and wait for the body to load
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g186458-Bridgend_Bridgend_County_South_Wales_Wales.html');
  await page.waitForSelector('body');

  // wait before evaluating the page
  await page.evaluate(() => {

    // get filters
    const filters = document.querySelectorAll('.restaurants-filters-Filters__wrapper--3z-oK .common-filters-FilterWrapper__container--3m4Qd')

    // loop through filters and select them
    for (let filter of Array.from(filters)) {
      const filterLabel = filter.querySelector('.common-filters-FilterWrapper__headerText--1G5Z1')

      if (filterLabel.innerText === 'Establishment Type') {
        filter.querySelector('._3kI1z_wP.v8kb8R34').click() // expand options
        filter.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][value="11776"]').click() // Bars & Pubs
      }

    }

    // get bars after filtering
    const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.restaurants-list-List__wrapper--3PzDL ._1llCuDZj')

    // loop through bars on the page
    for (let bar of Array.from(bars)) {
      const barTitle = bar.querySelector('.wQjYiB7z').innerText
      console.log(barTitle)
    }


  });

  // browser.close();

});
```

In the above, I've been able to simply open the webpage of my choosing, select a filter which then loads up my results, I can then get all of the `._1llCuDZj` on Page 1, **but then can't figure out how to click through to the next page**, and get the information from there as there's no URL param where I can just update the page number...

any suggestions?

Comment: There is a next button at the bottom of the page.. document.querySelectorAll('a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk').length this is the selector for next button. Just click on the button , wait for navigation and then call your logic of data extraction. Keep this repeating until you don't see a next button.

Comment: Sweet, my logic is the loop under `// get bars after filtering`, would this need to be inside of a function?